# Can you render jsp/html elements (i.e. a form:form) dynamically in one page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-data-jpa

I am new to web-dev, and coding in general, so I apologize if this question doesn't make sense.

Background: I am working on a web application utilizing the Spring Framework.  My application allows users to register a user account, post pictures, make comments on pictures, like pictures etc. (think of a mini Pintrest clone).  Users and comments (along with some other non-relevant entities) are all saved as in table entities in a MySQL database.

Problem: I would like users be able to edit their comments after they post them.  For the best user experience  I do not want users to be taken to a separate page with a form to edit their comment.  I would like user to be able to edit their comment in a single page/the same page, without rendering a new one. Flow goes something like this: User goes to their comment on a picture, presses an "edit" button/link and the comment is put in a text box (form:form) which is then editable.

So far I have tried conditional rendering with a boolean switch of "editPressed" but I can't seem to work out the logic.  Is this the correct approach or should something like JS be used here? (not sure how js handles form:forms) Below are some code snippets of the models and the .jsp where the comment would be edited.

.jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="eachComment" items="${allCommentsByPhotoId}">
    <div class="card-text d-flex gap-2 mb-4">

        <img class="user-comment-card" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1053/1053244.png" alt="" />

        <div>

            <div class="mb-2">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${ editPressed == false }">
                        <c:out value="${eachComment.user.getFirstName()} says: ${ eachComment.getComment() }"></c:out>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <span class="username">
                            <c:out value="${eachComment.user.getFirstName()}"></c:out>:
                        </span>
                        <c:out value="${ eachComment.getComment()}"></c:out>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3">



                <!--  -->

                <c:if test="${ eachComment.user.getId() == currentUser.id }">

                    <form:form action="/delete/${eachComment.getId()}" method="delete">
                        <p class="submit">
                            <input class="btn btn-danger del-cmt-btn" type="submit" value="Delete" />
                        </p>
                    </form:form>

                    <form:form action="/edit/comment/${eachComment.getId()}">
                        <p class="submit">
                            <input class="btn btn-secondary edit-cmt-btn" type="submit" value="Edit" />
                        </p>
                    </form:form>
                </c:if>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_comments_on_photo")
public class Comment {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String comment;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="photo_id")
    private Photo photo;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_likes_comment",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="comment_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
            )
    private List<User> usersWhoLikeComment;
    
    @Column(updatable=false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdAt;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date updatedAt;
```

USER MODEL:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Size(min=3)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Size(min=3)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Email
    private String email;
    
    @Size(min=8)
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirmation;
    
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
    
    
    //RELATIONSHIPS
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Photo> photos;
    
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_likes_photo",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="photo_id")
            )
    private List<Photo> likedPhotos;
    
    //NEW ONE-TO-MANY
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Comment> userComments;
    
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_likes_comment",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="comment_id")
            )
    private List<Comment> commentsUserLikes;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles;
```

PHOTO MODEL:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="photos")
public class Photo {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String photoURL;
    private String photoFileName;
    
    @NotEmpty
    private String photoTitle;
    @NotEmpty
    private String photoDescription;
    //will add tags later
    
    
    //RELATIONSHIPS
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_likes_photo",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="photo_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
            )
    private List<User> usersWhoLikePhoto;
    
    //NEW ONE-TO-MANY
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="photo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Comment> comments;
    
    //CREATED AND UPDATED AT
    @Column(updatable=false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdAt;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date updatedAt;
```

Comment: You might be overthinking this a bit.  Using only Javascript, you could have an edit button that hides the text area of the comment and unhides a text box containing the users comment.  A save button would be hooked to your spring backends "save" api to update your mysql db with the new comment using Fetch or Ajax or something.  When that backend service finishes updating the DB, it returns the results to your Fech or Ajax script in your JS and you hide the text box and unhide the text area and populate it with the new info from the DB (or use the comment data in memory).

Comment: Though rereading your question, form:form may complicate things because I'm not super familiar with JSP =/  So feel free to ignore me!

Comment: "So far I have tried conditional rendering with a boolean switch of 'editPressed'" - Does this mean you returned a new View from the server after they clicked the Edit button? In general there are these approaches: - Full server postback, - AJAX/partial postback, - Client focused Javascript (Return all the necessary client-side code up front so the server is not called -- not very JSP-ish)